# I need to do a function to resend OTP if user has not received it to update phone number functionality in laravel

Tags: laravel

Maybe I'm losing in a glass of water but I'm not understanding how implements this function, I use OTP code to verify phone when user compile the registration and when he try to update number. I'm using vonage, I put below my update method:

```
public function updatePhoneNumber(Request $request)
    {
        $basic  = new \Vonage\Client\Credentials\Basic("44bc4bb2", "fYVcLeo0lMhmtjm1");
        $client = new \Vonage\Client($basic);

        $request->validate([
            'telefono' => 'required|unique:users,telefono'
        ]);

        $telefono = $request->input('telefono');
        $otp = VerificationCode::create([
            'otp' => rand(10000, 99999),
            'expire_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)
        ]);

        $response = $client->sms()->send(
            new SMS($telefono, 'Help4You', 'Il tuo codice di verifica è:'. "\n" . $otp->otp)
        );
        
        $message = $response->current();
        
        if ($message->getStatus() == 0) {
            echo "The message was sent successfully\n";
        } else {
            echo "The message failed with status: " . $message->getStatus() . "\n";
        }

        User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->update([
            'telefono'=>Hash::make($request['telefono']),
        ]);
    }
```

how can I resend the otp if user has not received it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to have 2 separate functions. The logic for creating an OTP and sending the OTP is in a different function. Myself, I create a service for it and store it in a App\Services folder since it is a functionality I commonly use.

So, back to your question, separate the logic for creating an OTP and sending the otp, in your case, the following code should not be part of your function above

```php
$telefono = $request->input('telefono');
$otp = VerificationCode::create([
 'otp' => rand(10000, 99999),
 'expire_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)
]);

$response = $client->sms()->send(
 new SMS($telefono, 'Help4You', 'Il tuo codice di verifica è:'. "\n" . $otp-
>otp)
);
}
```

If you are implementing this is a separate class, remember to return the outcome of the sending of the OTP, it can either be success or error. Also, the only value you need to pass onto the function will be the recipient's cellphone number.

So, first time you send the OTP, you simply call the function or instance of the class, depending how you implemented.

Now, if the OTP was not delivered or a user wants to request another OTP, you call the function again.

You can add additional validation or a field on you table to check how many retries a user does for an OTP since the sms will cost your client money.

Once you separate your logic, you have now made your code to be reusable and is you need to use the same API to send a different SMS, you can do so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your help but i'm not understanding how pass the requested field in the send function, when user require OTP for the first time he insert his phone number but when he require another code how I can pass the field to the function?

Comment: Since you know the id of the user, you get their number from the database by first running a query to select their phone number from the database. If the answer worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks